# Preg_match_all add character before and after

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm using `preg_match_all` method to get the urls from inside the anchor tag on a page. It works but when i'm getting them, before adding them to the array i would like to wrap them with `'`(like this `'url'`):

```
preg_match_all('!<a href="(.*?)">!', $anchors, $urls);
```

Is there a way to do that? If yes, can you point me towards the right direction and the proper way that this could be done?

Thank you! :D

Comment: Naive answer, but is just `array_map(function ($e) { return "'".$e."'"; }, $urls[1]);` an option for you?

Comment: @ggorlen: You should put this as an answer.

Comment: He should X_X it was helpful :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a [regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) you could use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("yourfile.html");
$anchors= $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
$hrefs = [];

foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
    if ($anchor->hasAttribute("href")) {
        $hrefs[] = "'{$anchor->getAttribute('href')}'";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Thefourthbird! :D it works <3 didn't even knew about DOMDoc :D